# invalid syntax while concat mpeg files on windows PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7, ffmpeg

I am tying to concatenate all mpeg files together in one new file in windows 7, I adjusted the environment variables and running the code from python shell but it gives invalid syntax. Any help as I am new to Python and ffmpeg library?

My code:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in glob.glob("*.mpeg"); do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy output.mpeg
```

Thanks

Comment: it is not Python code so why do you run it in Python Shell ? It is Bash code so run it in Bash console/terminal.

Comment: @furas thanks for your reply. I found similar code in the ffmpeg library,where shall I run it, could you please help me?

Comment: Do you use Linux (or Mac) ? Do you know what Bash is ?

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: where did you get this code - it looks like mix of Python code (`for... glob()`) with `Bash` code. `Bash` needs rather `for f in "*.mpeg";` But to run it on Windows you will need some `Bash` - ie. `Cygwin`. So maybe better use python only to run `for ... glob` and save result in file and later use this file with `ffmpeg` in `cmd.exe`. And then you will no need `Bash`

Comment: Thanks Funas,
I already tried this but it also doesn't work.
printf "file '%s'\n" *.wav > mylist.txt
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output
Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: probably you need text without '\n' but I'm note sure

Comment: It gives an error with an incorrect syntax. I am running it from python shell and it highlights the double quotes .. not sure what is the problem

Comment: You can't run it Python shell because it is not Python code :)

Comment: so where shall I run it?

Comment: It Bash script so you should use Bash - but Windows doesn't use Bash :) You have to rewrite it in Windows commands or at least install `printf` from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) so you could run it in `cmd.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example code is mix or `Python` code and `Bash` code so it can't run in `Python Shell` nor in `Bash Shell` :)

On Linux it works in `Bash` as two commands:
(*Windows probably doesn't have `printf` command*)

```
printf "file '%s'\n" *.wav > input.txt 

ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mpeg
```

`Python` version which doesn't need `Bash`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import glob
import subprocess

# get Current Working Directory (CWD)
pwd = os.getcwd()

# get list of files 
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    #filenames = sys.argv[1:] # Linux
    filenames = glob.glob(sys.argv[1]) # Windows
else:
    filenames = glob.glob("*.mpg")

#print(filenames)

# generate "input.txt" file
with open("input.txt", "w") as f:
    for name in filenames:
        f.write("file '{}/{}'\n".format(pwd, name))
        #f.write("file '{}'\n".format(name))

# run ffmpeg 
subprocess.run('ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mpeg', shell=True)
```

And you can run it with or without argument ie. `"*.wav"`

```
python script.py *.wav
```

(tested only on Linux)

---

`printf` (and other `Bash` commands) for Windows: [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)

More on [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
But it shows an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SMH\Desktop\files\myscript.py", line 37, in <module>
    subprocess.run('ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mpeg', shell=True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'
Any help?

Comment: what python version do you use ? Python 2 ?

Comment: Try `call` instead of `run` - more https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#call-function-trio

Comment: Great, no error is showing up but there no output file, no sure why?

Comment: did you get `input.txt` file ? Check what you have inside. And then run `ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mpeg` in cmd.exe to see messages - maybe there are errors ie. you need install codec, or system can't find `ffmeg`,  etc.

Comment: you are right, I faced some errors but I solved it, but now it generates the output file from the cmd 'ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mpg' but doesn't generate it from the shell "subprocess.call('ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mpg', shell=True)" .. do you know why?
"

Comment: when I run Python script in console in Linux I can see all `ffmpeg` messages. Do you see any messages ? Maybe you need full path to `ffmpeg` or `input.txt`. Or you run script in wrong folder and it can't find files. You can `print(pwd)` in script to see `Current Working Directory`.

Comment: There is no messages or error in the shell and it create the list file but it doesn't create the output file, however in the cmd it creates it. I've already added the ffmpeg path in the system variables, not sure what shall I do ?

Comment: Maybe redirect output to file - add `> result.txt` in `subprocess.call('ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mpeg > result.txt' , shell=True)`. Or try `check_output` - `result = subprocess.check_output('ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mpeg' , shell=True)` and `print(result)`